# Using an IAM service role for credentials in AWS services with PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I have a PHP application running on elastic-beanstalk that uses some of AWS services, like S3, RDS and SES. 
I’m currently doing exactly what they don’t recommend, which is to hard code my credentials when I initialize a client for any of those services. 
Code looks like below:

```
$s3 = new S3Client([
    'region' => 'us-west-2',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => ‘**********’,
       'secret' => ‘******************’,
    ],
]);
```

I’m trying to move away from this and there’s plenty of AWS documentation on how to proceed but almost no examples that I could find. 
I’m considering using an IAM service role that has all the right policies attached to it. 
The steps are:

1. In the elastic beanstalk instance, the service role associated with that instance is `aws-elastic-beanstalk-role`
2. I attached all necessary policies to that service role for all the different services that I use. That was done from the management console.

Now how would I refer to the credentials in the client initialization like above? I honestly could not find an example on how to do it. I'm using AWS SDK for PHP version 3.0. 
Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `credentials` field from your s3 client parameters.

#### The Details

If you do not explicitly provide credential values, the AWS SDK will go through the [default credential providers chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials.html) to try and find the credentials.

It looks for credentials in this order:

1. Environment Variables
2. Profile or Config files on the file system
3. Assumed Roles (via EC2 instance profiles, Lambda roles, etc)

Assuming you don't have any environment variables or profiles configured, the SDK will use the role attached to your EC2 instance to sign requests with.

Comment: Thank you, it is that simple. It works fine without the credentials. Now that doesn't help me when testing it from a local deployment. Should I use the hard coded credentials in that case?

Comment: Run “aws configure” command and this will setup a config file on your local dev machine that the SDK can find and use.

Comment: Thank you, you saved the day here.

Comment: I have associated a role to EC2 instance and I am using AWS PHP SDK like you mentioned. But I am getting an error `include(AWS_SDK_User_Role.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`   
Where `AWS_SDK_User_Role` is the name of IAM Role attached to EC2 instance

Comment: @Sahil I'm having the same issue.  Were you ever able to resolve?

Comment: For me personally, this was happening because we were using an old version of Yii which had a different type of autoloader and that autoloader was interfering with AWS SDK trying to load the appropriate EC2 role automatically.
For fixing this, I disabled the Yii autoloader for few lines of code and in those lines, I let AWS SDK load the correct role which fixed the issue for me.

Comment: @Sahil thanks for your reply.  I resolved the issue on my own with a slightly different fix (interestingly I'm using Yii1 as well).  For me the problem was due to using an old version of guzzlehttp/promises (which is a dependency of AWS SDK).  [This line](https://github.com/guzzle/promises/blob/v1.3.1/src/Promise.php#L151) was causing issues but was fixed in a later version [here](https://github.com/guzzle/promises/blob/1.4.1/src/Promise.php#L148): `method_exists` called on a string caused Yii's autoloader to try to load as a class.  Upgrading guzzlehttp/promises fixed the issue.